# Como exibir o conteúdo de uma fila?

Tags: c#

Digo isso, pois já criei a Fila:

```
    Queue<string> Fila = new Queue<string>();
```

Mas não consigo exibi-la,

```
    string Pedido = (("Cliente:") + Cliente + (Environment.NewLine + "Produto:") + Produto + (Environment.NewLine + "Tamanho:") + Tamanho + (Environment.NewLine + "Quantidade") + Quantidade);
        //Adiciona o pedido a memória
```

As outras variáveis acima são como esta:

```
    Cliente = Console.ReadLine(); //Insere na memória o que foi digitado pelo usuário.
```

Na minha tentativa para exibir o conteúdo da Fila,

```
    if (resp == "S") //se a resposta for sim, exibe mensagem de sucesso e pergunta se deseja adicionar outro pedido
        {
            Fila.Enqueue(Pedido);
            Console.Write("Pedido Registrado! Deseja adicionar outro pedido? (S/N)");
            resp = Console.ReadLine();
            if (resp == "S")
            {
                Pedido = "";
                if (resp == "Verificar Fila")
                {
                    Console.Write("Fila: " + Fila);
                }

            }
```

O que é exibido é:

```
    Fila.Collections.Generic.Queue`1[System.String]
```

Answer (score 2):

Se quiser um modo mais compacto:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, fila));
```

O método estático `String.Join` une os itens de uma coleção com um caractere (nesse caso quebra de linha).

Veja [fucionando aqui](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EXWgpB).

Comment: É, provavelmente isso é mais próximo do que ele quer mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Como [`Queue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c(v=vs.110).aspx) implementa [`IEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx), você pode iterar todos os elementos com [`foreach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx):

```
Queue<string> fila = new Queue<string>();

fila.Enqueue("Teste 1");
fila.Enqueue("Teste 2");
fila.Enqueue("Teste 3");

foreach(string pedido in fila) {
    Console.WriteLine(pedido);
}
```

http://ideone.com/asyiVi

Comment: Mas nesse caso, não iria imprimir o pedido e não a fila de pedidos?

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "imprimir a fila"? A fila é o conjunto do que tem nela.

Comment: Pois eu quero poder imprimir a fila, então no caso de adicionar outro pedido a fila posteriormente, imprimiria a fila toda (Pedido 1 + Pedido 2, etc)

Comment: Então, o `foreach` que eu estou sugerindo varre a fila toda e imprime os itens, um por vez. Com isso você monta a saída que você quer.

Comment: Editei o exemplo colocando mais itens na fila, veja: http://ideone.com/asyiVi

Comment: Mas considere que no caso, meu pedido é: string Pedido = (("Cliente:") + Cliente + (Environment.NewLine + "Produto:") + Produto + (Environment.NewLine + "Tamanho:") + Tamanho + (Environment.NewLine + "Quantidade") + Quantidade);
        //Adiciona o pedido a memória

Comment: E as variáveis Cliente, Produto, Tamanho, etc seguem o padrão:  Cliente = Console.ReadLine(); //Insere na memória o que foi digitado pelo usuário.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24244/discussion-between-harison-and-bfavaretto).

Comment: @Harison Não pude continuar a discussão naquele momento. Mas a resposta do MarcusVinicius não resolve o seu problema?